# Duplicate domains - How to rank for all of them?

Tags: ranking

So I have a PDM and 2 EDM that redirect to the first. Neither of these EDMs rank at all, but the primary one does just fine.

Right now, I'm re-directing in the `.htaccess` of both EDMs to the primary, but I'd like to rank for all 3 (just with different searches).

Essentially, my company offers 3 main services that work together to form a whole. I do quite well in all 3 areas, but I really want to rank for *keywordsA* and *keywordsB*, as I only currently rank for *keywordsC*.

I really don't want to put a *lot* of work into the 2 other domains, but enough that it will work.

## What approach should I use?

1- Create 3 entirely unique websites and try to maintain them all (ugh).

2- Create 2 awesome "landing sites", keyword rich and straight to the point.

3- Just try to promote the *heck* out of the primary and leave the other 2 in the dust (but of of competitors reach, of course).

Answer (score 1):

> Create 3 entirely unique websites and try to maintain them all (ugh).

What do you think will be more successful? One site getting 100% of your time? Or three sites that get 33% of your time?

> Create 2 awesome "landing sites", keyword rich and straight to the point.

The landing sites wont rank well because no one is going to to want to link to them due to lack of quality content. Plus if this looks like an unnatural link pattern you run the risk of penalties from the search engines.

> Just try to promote the heck out of the primary and leave the other 2 in the dust (but of of competitors reach, of course).

That's the best course of action. Make the site darn good and get the word out there about it.